# How Do I Use a string a variable in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, variable-assignment

I am very very new to PowerShell. I am trying to create a script to create new user in AD, with prompts for each switch, but I am struggling a little with the Syntax and was hoping someone could help me.

Currently I have:

```
$FirstName = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the first name"

$LastName = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the last name"

New-ADUser -Name $FirstName.$LastName -GivenName $FirstName -Surname $LastName
```

The above gives me the prompts that I want, but then when I input the last name, it returns the following error:

```
"New-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or 
empty, and then try the command again.
At line:3 char:18
+ New-ADUser -Name $FirstName.$LastName -GivenName $FirstName -Surname  ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
"
```

I assume this is because I have not put the correct entry in after -Name.

Hopefully one of you can help me and give me an explanation & example as to what I should do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get PowerShell code to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186776/unable-to-get-powershell-code-to-work)

Comment: try formatting $FirstName and $LastName to strings.  New-ADUser -Name [string]::Format( "{0}.{1}", $FirstName, $LastName) -GivenName $FirstName -Surname $LastName

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
New-ADUser -Name $FirstName.$LastName -GivenName $FirstName -Surname $LastName
```

to:

```
New-ADUser -Name "$FirstName.$LastName" -GivenName $FirstName -Surname $LastName
```

Comment: To clarify what's going on, the issue is that the period is an operator. `$FirstName.$LastName` means "For the object represented by the variable `$FirstName`, get the value of the property whose name is the value of the variable `$LastName`."  In other words, `'John'.'Smith'` and not `'John.Smith'`.  For a working example: `$Drive = Get-Item C:\; $Property = 'PSIsContainer'; $Drive.$Property` should output `True` because the property `PSIsContainer` of `$Drive` has a value of true. If the property doesn't exist, however, you'll just get a null value.